# Monitor screens turn to one solid color during the startup

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi

I'm having some strange issue here. Sometimes (in the last time it seems like more often than before) when I turn on my computer, it passes the POST screen and during the Windows Splash screen, both connected monitors turn their screen to one solid color. On every monitor, is a different color and the colors themselves are always different. (Most often green and brownish color.) In most cases, it happens during the Splash screen loading and less often also on the Windows Login screen. Interesting is, that if I get pass the login screen it will never happen until the next startup. Also, it only happens when both monitors are connected. If I'll start up my computer with only one monitor connected, log in to Windows and then connect the other monitor, I'm fine.

I'm running a machine with nVidia GTX 1050 2G with 2 monitors connected:

- Samsung SyncMaster via DVI-DVI @ 1680x1050
- LG W1942 via DVI-HDMI @ 1440x900

on Windows 10 x64.

What do you think could be the root cause here. Is it a graphics card, motherboard, drivers or even power supply?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Have you installed the latest [NVIDIA Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and [Samsung driver](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/)?

Comment: Yes, I have all the drivers updated to the latest version.

Comment: In that case this might be anything, software or hardware, we have no way of knowing.

Comment: I know it's really difficult to guess what could be the cause. I was hoping that maybe somebody had the same issue and found a solution. 
EDIT: 'Thanks' for -1 anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to resolve this issue by Resetting optimized defaults in BIOS. Not sure what was the cause tho. I haven't changed in the BIOS anything recently.